# Installation fails when installing 64-bit version of Ubuntu but not 32 bit

Tags: system-installation, kernel, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a flash drive with Ubuntu 13.10 on it that I'm trying to install. When I try and install the 64 bit version on my computer I get this error:

`Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

I only get this error when I try and install the 64 bit version. All my hardware is 64 bit hardware.

I searched high and low to find a solution, but nothing seemed relevant to the issue I was having.

When I try and boot from flash drive, it gives me that error. Even if I select try Ubuntu without installing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?   See
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM   Check the number
   against the listing in the link for your release listed at
   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.

2) Did you select the media check before trying to install? 
    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

3)  Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on
    your PC? Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with
    a bad install media.